# How to plot a plane passing through the centre of a 3d scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

I've plotted a plane passing through the center of the scatter plot but it seems to push the scatter plot to a side. I probably think it is because of the scaling. I am in a dilemma as to how to plot the plane just to the size of the scatter plot.

Here's what I have tried.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
df=pd.read_csv('wr.csv')
df=df.sample(frac=1)

X=np.linspace(0,df['fixed acidity'].shape)
Y=np.linspace(0,df['fixed acidity'].shape)
x,y=np.meshgrid(X,Y)
z=x*0+y*0+np.mean(np.square(df['fixed acidity']))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df.index, df['fixed acidity'], np.square(df['fixed acidity']), s=5,color='black')
ax.scatter(np.mean(df.index),np.mean(df['fixed acidity']),np.mean(np.square(df['fixed acidity'])),color='orange',s=300)
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,alpha=0.5)
```

[Original plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjpQ0.png)

[This is the plot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7J9m.png)

I want the plane passing through the centre and keep the plane the same size as the scatter plot.

Comment: For your scatter plot, the y-values seem to be between about 6 and 16. The plane, on the contrary, goes until y=1600. You might want to limit the y-values.  E.g. `Y=np.linspace(0,df['fixed acidity'].max().astype(int)+2)`.

Comment: This works only for the `fixed acidity` column is there a way to plot the plane dynamically irrespective of the column? (You can reproduce the code with the `wine quality` dataset)

Comment: If `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` are the min/max of the x and y values used in the scatter plot, and `zval` the height where you want the rectangle, you could try `ax.plot_surface([[xmin, xmax], [xmin, xmax]], [[ymin, ymin], [ymax, ymax]], [[zval, zval], [zval, zval]], alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: Thank you!! That works just as expected. To add on how to do you find the equation of a plane? In general cases where there is a meshgrid it would have been easy but in this case I have no idea as how to do get the equation of a plane. I would also be happy if you just help me finding the points lying on  the plane. @JohanC